# Is this extra step necessary when freeing dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c++, arrays

During the expansion of a dynamically allocated array, I find myself writing this :

```
void HPQueue::expandCapacity() {
  char **prevArray = array;
  capacity *= 2;
  array = new char*[static_cast<size_t>(capacity)];
  for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    array[i] = new char;
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    array[i] = prevArray[i];

LINE XX: delete prevArray[i]; <----------- This line seems to be the problem, Since it also deletes array[i]
  }
  delete[] prevArray; 
}
```

But this line is necessary if initially the constructor looks something like this:

```
HPQueue::HPQueue::() {
  capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
  array = new char*[static_cast<size_t>(logSize)];
  for (int i = 0; i < logSize; i++) {
    array[i] = new char;
  }
  count = 0;
}
```

Note :

```
  /* instances variables */
  char **array;
  size_t count;
```

Is this `LINE XX:` not necessary ?

Comment: in your example the `LINE XX:` is needed, because of this line `array[i] = new char;`. Each data allocated by `new` must be deallocated by `delete` or `delete[]`

Comment: @Raffallo that's my understanding but by doing so, it seems to corrupt  ```array[i]```

Comment: Any particular reason why you try to reinvent the wheel, a.k.a. `<vector>`, and not use the smart pointers offered by `<memory>` to do it?

Comment: What is `count`?  And since `array` and `prevArray` supposedly have differing sizes, why are you assuming both have at least `count` items?

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating individual `char`s?

Comment: In addition, `capacity *= 2;array = new char*[static_cast<size_t>(capacity)];` -- if `new[]` throws an exception, the `capacity` member is now erroneous due to it being changed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ```count```holds the number of elements currently enqueued. so am not assuming anything

Comment: Can you prove that `expandCapacity` is called **only** when `count == capacity`?

Comment: @caleth yes i do have a line in the `enqueue` method that check this

Comment: @base10 yes, when `array[i]` is deleted it can't be used any more and should be changed to the `nullptr` and before next use should be allocated again by the `new`. Thats why you could use `std::vector` or something like that

Comment: @DevSolar i am infact in the process of covering course material on c++, this being an implementation of PQueue with dynamically allocated memory, initial i did have an implementation using a vector. so that's why, my belief is there's nothing wrong with understanding the inner works of a system, through reimplementation

Comment: Then allow me to toss in a few observations: capacity should not need to be cast, should be size_t to begin with. Memory should not be owned by naked pointers (use `unique_ptr`, removing the need to `delete`). Use range-for. Use member initializer lists. Don't use `#define` for numeric constants. There is more, but these were the ones that stood out to me the most, ad-hoc.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't be calling `new char` for the first `count` elements of `array`. You should be copying from the first `count` elements of `prevArray`.

You don't need to call `new char` *at all*. If you use `nullptr` instead, you can still safely `delete[] array[i]` when you remove an element.

But you shouldn't be doing this. In order of preference:

- Use `std::vector<std::string> array`, it does all this for you.
- Use `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<char[]>[]> array; std::size_t capacity;` and reassign with `array = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<char[]>[]>(capacity);` and move with `std::move(prevArray.get(), prevArray.get() + count, array.get());`
- Use `char **array; std::size_t capacity;`, reassign with `array = new char*[capacity];` and move with `std::copy_n(prevArray, count, array);`

So if you are **required** to go with the last one, you get

```
HPQueue::HPQueue()
 : capacity(INITIAL_CAPACITY), 
   array(new char*[INITIAL_CAPACITY]),
   count(0)
{
   std::fill_n(array, capacity, nullptr);
}

void HPQueue::expandCapacity() {
  char **prevArray = array;
  capacity *= 2;
  array = new char*[capacity];
  auto pos = std::copy_n(prevArray, count, array);
  std::fill_n(pos, capacity - count, nullptr);
  delete[] prevArray; 
}
```

Comment: well the reason i do that is so ```Because for some reason you are dynamically allocating each char```is to allow to work with strings

Comment: @base10: That will not make it work with strings.  Strings must be stored contiguously, calling `new char` N times does not give you contiguous allocation, it gives you single characters scattered all over the place.  And your loop calling `new char` is useless because you immediately overwrite the pointers in the next loop, leaking the allocation.

Comment: @BenVoigt now i see why he was puzzled by this thank you for reminding me

Comment: @base10 if you are ever assigning `array[i] = new char[]`, then you will need to track which `i` had a `new char` and which had a `new char[]` to call `delete` or `delete[]`. It's easier to just not.